# move a group of sheets that contain a table and slicer using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to  move a group of sheets that contain a table and slicer. I tried using vba. It moves all sheets but slicer disappears. I have multiple slicers in multiple tabs. Help me with vba code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.